# how to get from jsonb subJesonb by key array in postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have jsonb field and array keys how get sub jsonb

field = `{"f1":1, "f2":null, "f3":"fff", "f4":"4"}`

kes = `["f1", f3]`

We need to get: `{"f1":1, "f3":"fff"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could unnest both, join the results and aggregate back:

Something like:

```
select jsonb_object_agg(i.k, i.v)
from jsonb_each('{"f1":1, "f2":null, "f3":"fff", "f4":"4"}'::jsonb) as i(k,v)
  join jsonb_array_elements_text('["f1", "f3"]') t(k) on t.k = i.k
```